# Reorder boxplot based on multiple variables without changing the dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe `data`, with multiple columns.

```
dput(head(data,15))

Counts samples.sample_name  samples.class samples.cluster
0      F1S4_161018_001_A01  Glutamatergic   LGN Exc BTNL9
2      F1S4_161018_001_B01  Glutamatergic   LGN Exc BTNL9
41     F1S4_161018_001_C01  GABAergic       LGN Inh NTRK1
0      F1S4_161018_001_E01  Glutamatergic   LGN Exc PAX3
1      F1S4_161018_001_F01  Glutamatergic   LGN Exc BTNL9
0      F1S4_161018_001_G01  Glutamatergic   LGN Exc PAX3
10     F1S4_161018_001_H01  GABAergic       LGN Inh LAMP1
25     F1S4_161018_001_F01  GABAergic       LGN Inh PAX3
```

There is a total of 15000 rows and each row is one cell.

I want to make a boxplot of counts within each cluster where the x-axis is ordered by counts (just from low to high) but also ordered by class. So first all clusters ordered by counts that are GABAergic, next that are Glutamatergic, etc.

I have this line of code now:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data[which(data$Counts > 0), ], 
       aes(x = reorder(samples. cluster, Counts), y = Counts)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = samples.class)) + 
  labs(title = paste('Expression of DMD in the human cortex', brain_area), 
       x = 'Cluster', y = 'Log2(Counts)') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), y = -1, stat = 'count', colour = 'blue', size = 5) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, max(data$Counts))) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), 
        legend.position = 'none')
```

I have this plot now:

[image]

And I want something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to add something to reorder the boxplot as described before, without changing the dataframe? Since I have many different datasets with different clusternames it would be a lot of work to reorder 'by hand' by just using a vector, so I want to know if there is another solution.

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and expected plots. Use `dput` for data.

Comment: So you want to go from a boxplot to a barplot? Maybe I got it wrong but that's what it seems like.

Comment: No I still want a boxplot, but ordered in the way the barplot is.

Comment: The labels are not visible(illegible?).

Comment: Sorry these are the only pictures I have. But on the x-axis the sample.clusters are shown, on the y axis the Log2 of the counts.

Comment: Could you add data with `dput(head(df,15))`?

Comment: I think this is only possible when the data is available on your computer? I work on an external server since this are very large datasets.

Comment: Could you be more precise about the exact order you want ?